# retina display and scaling issues

Tags: webkit, viewport, retina-display

I have a web app designed for the iPhone 3 using css3 & html5.  Moving to the iPhone 4 and retina display has been a bit of a challenge, even after reading about "css pixels" vs "physical pixels".

My web app creates quite a few pages that are "hidden" off the right side of the screen and buttons on the "home screen" slide the desired page onto the screen.  I use the following transform to hide pages offscreen:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(+100%,0,0)
```

All works well on the iPhone 3 but the iPhone 4 displays both pages side by side, I presume because the retina display is twice as wide.

I've been able to solve that problem but changing my meta tag from:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
```

to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
 minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=no">
```

and using the display attribute to hide the pages offscreen:

```
display: none
```

but I still have one problem I can't solve.  On the iPhone 3 rotating the device to landscape scales the text larger.  On the iPhone 4 the wider screen is used but no scaling of text occurs.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Tia

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this behavior through the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` CSS property:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape */
}
```

The use of this property is described further in the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW16).